# Air desktop application CSS file and image url

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've got a StyleableTextField that displays very basic HTML.
This css file is calling on main class like this :

```
<fx:Style source="assets/skin/1styles.css"/>
```

My project directory is like this

MainLevel

```
  ____ src
       mainApp.mxml
       ____ assets
                    ____ skin
                                  1styles.css
                                  ____ assets
```

For example with this code, an error appear about wrong path

```
.nestedTabButton {
    skin: Embed("./assets/blank.png");
    font-weight: normal;
    text-roll-over-color: #CCCCCC;
    text-roll-over-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

So could you help me to find the good path ?

Best regards

Comment: You have two `assets` folders. Not obvious which one you wanted. What happens if you try as `skin: Embed("/assets/blank.png");`? Or maybe use `./src/assets/blank.png`. PS: What is the exact/full error message?

Comment: The picture blank.png are located on '/assets/skin/assets/blank.png'. I try kin: Embed("./src/assets/skin/assets/blank.png"); but I have the same error : Instruction Embed erronée dans la feuille de style ; impossible de résoudre la source Embed("./src/assets/skin/assets/blank.png"). Thanks for helping

Comment: You say _"The picture blank.png are located on '/assets/skin/assets/blank.png'"_ so does using `skin: Embed("/assets/skin/assets/blank.png");` not solve the error?

Comment: I already try skin: Embed("/assets/skin/assets/blank.png"); But this path not solve the error ... It's strange because the same path with Flex builder works well...

Comment: PS: See if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23901386/2057709) helps you. It suggests editing the **working directory** in Debugger setup. I don't use Visual Studio so I can't test anything myself.